# How can I paginate EmbeddedDocumentListField objects in Mongoengine?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Here are my classes. What is a good way to query the `User` for the embedded `Review` objects and paginate it somehow?

```
class Review(EmbeddedDocument):
    review_body = StringField(required=True)
    review_stars = FloatField(required=True, default=0)
    reviewer = LazyReferenceField('User')
    review_date = DateTimeField()

class User(Document):
    userreviews = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Review)
```

I'm sure I can get the total easily with `.count()` but I'm not sure how to skip and query for only a portion of the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, it seems, lies in the way I was querying the database. I was doing it incorrectly for what I was trying to accomplish.

**What wasn't working:**

```
userprofile: user.User = user.User.objects(
    username=request.form["username"]).get()
all_reviews = userprofile.userreviews # work with objects here
```

**What should work:**

Using `.filter(`) and `.slice()` I can get the embedded `Review` objects like so:

```
reviews = user.User.objects.filter(username=request.form["username"]).fields(
    slice__userreviews=[0, 2])

for r in reviews:
    print(r.userreviews)
```

This will return 2 review objects starting at the index of 0. Then I just need to use `.count()` to get the total amount and I should have the 3 elements I need for pagination.